# .htaccess advanced conditions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

guys! I reserched about this, but I cannot find something for my case. I need the .htaccess file to assure this 3 rules:

1) if it's exactly "www.example.com", goes to "www.example.com/home.php"

2) if it contains ".php", makes no change, goes to requested php

3) only if previous rules had no effect, subpage should be taken as username:
www.example.com/peter => www.example.com/user.php?nickname=peter

Examples:

```
www.example.com => www.example.com/home.php

www.example.com/login.php => www.example.com/login.php

www.example.com/john => www.example.com/user.php?nickname=john
```

Thank you a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken,

```
for: www.example.com => www.example.com/home.php
RewriteRule ^/$   home.php [NC,QSA,L]

www.example.com/john => www.example.com/user.php?nickname=john
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z]+)/$ user.php?nickname=$1 [QSA,L]

or if you want specific

RewriteRule ^john/$ user.php?nickname=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hope this helps.